There's a problem with my System.in for the Scanner
I have a problem with my eclipse project where I'm using the Scanner but the error log tells me that 'in' in the System.in cannot be resolved or not in field. Here is my code:
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class System {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
    
    }
}

And here is my error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
in cannot be resolved or is not a field
out cannot be resolved or is not a field
out cannot be resolved or is not a field

I've tried to update and reinstall my eclipse but the problem remains

It's because your class is named "System". Rename your class and it works.
Or, change System.in and System.out to java.lang.System.in and java.lang.System.out respectively.

Owh, I didn't realized that. Thank you very much

You're welcome. And keep learning!
